# NSNumberFormatter - get currency symbol for currency code

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

*This question is similar to, but there was no answer that worked on that question - [NSNumberFormatter currency symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742983/nsnumberformatter-currency-symbol)*

---

I am using an NSNumberFormatter to format currency values and this works fine as long as the currency is the currency of the user's locale. But I also need to show currency values that are possibly not the default currency for the user's locale (such as showing GBP when the current locale is en_US or showing JPY when the locale is fr_FR).

So I would like to display those currencies using the rules set by the current locale, but I do not know how to get the currency symbol after setting the currency code.

For example, here is how the NSNumberFormatter is configured:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

- (lldb) po [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:12.50]]

  - $12.50
- (lldb) po currencyFormatter.currencySymbol

  - $
- (lldb) po currencyFormatter.currencyCode

  - USD
- (lldb) po currencyFormatter.internationalCurrencySymbol

  - USD

All those are correct. But then, if I set the currency code to GBP, like so:

```
currencyFormatter.currencyCode = @"GBP"
```

I get the following where the formatted string is correct and the currency code is correct, but the currency symbol and international currency symbol are incorrect.

- (lldb) po [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:12.50]]

  - £12.50
- (lldb) po currencyFormatter.currencySymbol

  - $   *- wrong, this should be £*
- (lldb) po currencyFormatter.currencyCode

  - USD
- (lldb) po currencyFormatter.internationalCurrencySymbol

  - USD  *- wrong, this should be GBP*

But it is really weird to me that the `stringFromNumber` method would return the correctly formatted value, with the correct currency symbol but accessing the `currencySymbol` property directly returns the incorrect currency symbol.

I need to be able to access the currency symbol so I can make it smaller and shift its baseline so that the currency symbol is smaller and offset from the rest of the text.

Does anyone know if I am doing anything wrong or how to get the currency symbol after setting the currency code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forcing `currencyCode` to 'GPD' but other properties of currency style as `symbol`, `internationalCurrencySymbol`, ... They depend on `Locale`. Check this:

```objectivec
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_UK"];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:123456]]);
NSLog(@"%@", formatter.currencySymbol);
NSLog(@"%@", formatter.currencyCode);
NSLog(@"%@", formatter.internationalCurrencySymbol);
```

It will print:

```
£123,456.00
£
GBP
GBP
```

Then edit only the currency code to `USD` as the way you did:

```
US$123,456.00
£
USD
GBP
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is consistent with what I have found as well. But what I am trying to figure out is how the `stringFromNumber` method seems to get the correct currency symbol after the currency code is set. How does that method work because it is getting the correct symbol. In your example, with the en_UK locale and USD currency code, it gets `US$` as the currency symbol, which is correct. But how does it do that? I just need to either be able to get the currency symbol for the currency code in the specified locale or somehow parse the symbol from the `stringFromNumber` result.

Comment: From my experience, Apple document did not say much about it. I thought they have  priority sorting like: (`currencyCode` | `currencySymbol`) > `locale`. These are settable properties, just know how it works and you can customize it the way you want.

Comment: Thanks so much. I ended up setting the `positiveFormat` so that the currency symbol was surrounded by pipe characters (any delimiter would work as long as no locale uses that) and then used the `stringFromNumber` method of the formatter to format the number zero (any number would work) and then parsed the resulting string to get the start and stop delimiters and took the substring between those delimiters. This has worked out really well so far.